# Postion of \backaddress

Tags: spacing, positioning, letterhead, addresses

I need to change the position of the `\backaddress` field in horizontal like in the picture below:

**UPDATE:**

I found out that the `\backaddress{\scriptsize Adress here!}` line is centered in the address box. Is there a command to align the line to the left?

```
\backaddress{\scriptsize Adress here!}

\nobackaddressrule
\date{<%= Time.now.to_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")%>}
\nowindowtics
\begin{letter}
...
...
...
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8.75pt]{dinbrief}

\usepackage{<%= LATEX_BRIEF_STY %>}

\begin{document}

  \fontsize{10pt}{13}%
  \raggedright
  \selectfont
  \backaddress{\scriptsize Backaddress here}
  \nobackaddressrule
  \nowindowtics
  \begin{letter}
     {%
  \protect\parbox{8cm}{Company\strut}\\
     John Due \\
     Street No. 1\\
     New York City}

  \adressrules


  \subject{\textsf {Order No. 1234}}

  \opening{Hello Mr. Due,}


  \closing{Kind Regards,}
  \end{letter}

  \newpage

  {\LARGE Produktdetails}

  \vspace{2cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke added an example above :)

Comment: Your example is not working, because of all the placeholders you are using. Please read the answers to the question linked by Henri. There you will find also links to howtos.

Comment: @Schweinebacke updated the question and example

Comment: It's still not working because of `\usepackage{<%= LATEX_BRIEF_STY %>}`. Please test your example before posting! BTW: `dinbrief` does not provide an option `8.75pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dinbrief` isn't very flexible. You have to patch the code to left align the backaddress:

```
% Example from the dinbrief manual extended by some code for left
% aligned backaddress
\documentclass[12pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage{german}
% added >>>>
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ka@db@tstoaddress}{% in command \ka@db@tstoaddr
  \hbox to \addrwd{\hfil {\ka@db@bafntsel\@backaddress}\hfil}% replace
}{%
  \hbox to \addrwd{{\ka@db@bafntsel\@backaddress}\hfil}% rby
}{}{}
\makeatother
% <<<<

\address{R"udiger Kurz\\
Am See 1\\
76133 Karlsruhe}
\backaddress{R. Kurz, Am See 1, 76133 Karslruhe}
\signature{R"udiger Kurz}
\place{Karlsruhe}
\begin{document}
\phone{0721}{222222}
\begin{letter}{Deutsche Bundespost\\
Fernmeldeamt Karlsruhe\\
Postfach 7300\\[\medskipamount]
{\bf 76131 Karlsruhe}}
\yourmail{01.04.93}
\sign{123456}
\subject{Betrieb eines Mikrowellensenders}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
anbei sende ich Ihnen eine Kopie der bisherigen Genehmigung f"ur
unseren Mikrowellenherd...
... Ihre Bem"uhungen im voraus vielen Dank.
\closing{Mit freundlichen Gr"u"sen,}
\ps{Wir bitten um schnelle Erledigung.}
\cc{Deutsche Bundespost\\
Karlsruher Privatfunk \\
S"uddeutscher Rundfunk}
\encl{Abschrift der Urkunde}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Your example wasn't compilable, so I've used the example from the `dinbrief` manual to have a MWE, which results in:

[image]

An ugly hack alternative to the patch would be appending `\hfill` to the backaddress:

```
\backaddress{R. Kurz, Am See 1, 76133 Karslruhe\hfill}
```

The result is same as shown above.

After Klaus Braune has gone much to early, it seems that `dinbrief` is not longer maintained. Unfortunately there are some known [issues, e.g., with the redefinition of `\enddocument` in `dinbrief`](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/20166/dinbrief-mit-pythontex-the-pytxcode-file-appears-to-have-an-outdated-format-or-be-invalid). So maybe switching to a maintained, more flexible letter class would be a suggestion.

Comment: thx, this is working!